# Which of the following are true about the group $\Bbb{Z}_6×\Bbb{Z}_9×\Bbb{Z}_{15}/\langle(5,5,3)\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

Let, $\displaystyle{G=\frac{\Bbb{Z}_6\times\Bbb{Z}_9\times\Bbb{Z}_{15}}{\langle(5,5,3)\rangle}}$ Which of the following are ture about $G$? The given options are-
(a) $G$ is cyclic.
(b) $G$ is Abelian. 
(c) $Z(G)$ is non-trivial.
(d) Order of $G$ is prime.
I have tried this-
Since $\Bbb{Z}_6\times\Bbb{Z}_9\times\Bbb{Z}_{15}$ is abelian, so the quotient group $G$ is abelian too. Hence, $G=Z(G)$. So (b), (c) are true.
Now, order of $\langle (5,5,3)\rangle$= the order of $(5,5,3)$=lcm$(6,9,5)=5\times9×2=90$. So order of $G=\frac{6×9×15}{90}=9=3^2$. Which is not prime. Hence, (d) is false.
But I cannot say anything about (a). A group of order $9=3^3$ may not be cyclic.
Can anyone prove or disprove option (a)? Thanks for assistance in advance.

Comment: $\langle (5,5,3)\rangle$ is a subgroup of the whole product, right, not just $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$?

Comment: Yes yes, it's a subgroup of the whole product

Comment: You can [compute the Smith normal form](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxzVLBVyE0sKcqs0IiK0omONtMx0DGI1Yk20LGE0gY6hqZAhqmOqY5xbKwmL5ejXnFuZklGfFp-Ua6GJgA9aRGi&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) of the relations matrix to show that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(2,0,0)+H,(0,3,0)+H$ and $(0,0,5)+H$ have order $3$ in the quotient.  This implies $G$ is not cyclic.

Comment: This is significant because $ (2,0,0) \not \equiv (0,3,0) \not \equiv (0,0,5) \mod \langle (5,5,3) \rangle$, right?

Comment: That's right.  @healynr

Comment: But a cyclic group may have different elements of same order. The subgroups of a particular order should be unique. How could you say the subgroups generated by these elements are not same?

Comment: The point is that they are different elements of the quotient.  That's because they don't differ by an element of $H$.  A cyclic group, in this case of order $9$, only has $\varphi(3)=2$ elements of order $3$.

Comment: Ok nice idea thumbs up